# polars concat columns of array typ into columns of string type

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-polars

I would like to concat dataframe Array[String] column into String column using polars only native functions. Is it possible?

```
df1 = pl.DataFrame({
    'col1': [["1.0", "1.0"], ["2.0", "3.0"]],
    'col2': ["a", "a"],
})
```

This is the expected output I would like to achieve.

```
  col1    | col2
"1.0,1.0" | "a"
"2.0,3.0" | "a"
```

I don't want to use custom python functions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can obtain that with the `arr.join` transformation:

```
df1.with_columns(
    pl.col('col1').arr.join(',')
)

# result
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────┬──────┐
│ col1    ┆ col2 │
│ ---     ┆ ---  │
│ str     ┆ str  │
╞═════════╪══════╡
│ 1.0,1.0 ┆ a    │
│ 2.0,3.0 ┆ a    │
└─────────┴──────┘
```